# Why is my mongoose connection being closed when i call a function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to read a stored "user" in my mongo database. I'm using an express server that connects with the data base when I start the server. My route /getUser calls a function getUser() when my program enters the function the database is no longer connected. But the connection with the database is actually working when i start my server. These are my server and getUser codes

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const cron = require("node-cron");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { addVideo } = require("../services/addVideo.js");
const { deletePlaylist } = require("../services/deletePlaylist.js");
const { deleteVideo } = require("../services/deleteVideo.js");
const { updateTitle } = require("../services/updateTitle.js");
const { getOriginalTitle } = require("../services/getOriginalTitle.js");
const { checkValidLink } = require("../services/checkValidLink.js");
const { checkPassword } = require("../services/checkPassword.js");
const { getUser } = require("../services/getUser.js");
const { addUser } = require("../services/addUser.js");
const { resetDaylyInsertions } = require("../services/resetDaylyInsertions.js");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const connectionString = process.env.DB_URI;

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(PORT, async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(connectionString);
        console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
        console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", error);
    }
});

cron.schedule('0 0 * * *', () => {
    console.log('Running a job at 00:00 at America/Sao_Paulo timezone');
    resetDaylyInsertions();
},{
    scheduled: true,
    timezone: "America/Sao_Paulo"
});

app.get("/", function (req,res){

    res.send({status:"This definitelly is an API"})

})

app.get("/loginValidate/:username/:password", async function(req,res){

    try{
        let user = await getUser(req.params.username);
        if(user === null) res.send({status:"Unvalid user"});
        else{
            if(!checkPassword(user,req.params.password)) res.send({status:"Incorrect password"});
            else res.send(user);
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(400).json({message: error.message}); 
    }  

})

app.get("/getUser/:username", async function(req,res){

    console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);

    try{
        console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
        let user = await getUser(req.params.username);
        res.send(user);
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(400).json({message: error.message}); 
    }  

})

app.post("/createUser/:username/:password",async function(req,res){

    try {
        let user = await getUser(req.params.username);
        if(!user){
            await addUser(req.params.username,req.params.password);
            res.status(201).send({status:"User created succesfully!"});
        }
        else{
            res.status(201).send({status:"Username already being used!"});
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(400).json({message: error.message});
    }

})

app.post("/addVideo/:link/:playlist/:username",async function(req,res){

    try {
        let validation = checkValidLink(req.params.link);
            if(validation === false){
                res.status(201).send({status:"Invalid link!"});
            }
            else{
                let validatedId = validation;
                let user = await getUser(req.params.username);
                if(user.daylyInsertions >= 10){
                    res.status(201).send({status:"Max dayly insertions reached!"});
                }
                else{
                    await addVideo(validatedId,req.params.playlist,req.params.username);
                    res.status(201).send({status:"Video added succesfully!"});
                }
            }   
        }
        
    catch(error) {
        res.status(400).json({message: error.message});
    }

})

app.delete("/deletePlaylist/:username/:playlistId",async function(req,res){

    try{
        await deletePlaylist(req.params.username,req.params.playlistId);
        res.status(201).send({status:"Playlist deleted succesfully!"});
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(400).json({message: error.message});
    }
    
});


app.delete("/deleteVideo/:username/:playlistId/:videoId",async function(req,res){

    try{
        await deleteVideo(req.params.username,req.params.playlistId,req.params.videoId);
        res.status(201).send({status:"Video deleted succesfully!"});
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(400).json({message: error.message});
    }
    
});

app.put("/updateTitle/:username/:playlistId/:videoId/:newTitle",async function(req,res){

    try{
        await updateTitle(req.params.username,req.params.playlistId,req.params.videoId,req.params.newTitle);
        res.status(201).send({status:"Title updated succesfully!"});
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(400).json({message: error.message});
    }

})

app.put("/getOriginalTitle/:username/:playlistId/:videoId",async function(req,res){

    try{
        await getOriginalTitle(req.params.username,req.params.playlistId,req.params.videoId);
        res.status(201).send({status:"Title updated succesfully!"});
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(400).json({message: error.message});
    }

})
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const userSchema = require("../schemas/userSchema");

async function getUser(username){

    console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
    
    const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema,"users");

    console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);

    const foundUser = await User.findOne({user:username});

    return foundUser;

}

module.exports.getUser = getUser;
```

When i start the server and try to call the /getUser route i get these connection states on my terminal

```
Connected to MongoDB
Server started on port 3001
1
1
0
0
```

I've already tried to reinstall mongoose, i've checked and mongoose is installed in the same version in any part of the code. I don't know what could be closing the connection since this code was working before.

Comment: _`/loginValidate/:username/:password`_... yikes! Don't put credentials in the URL

Comment: I would invert the connection logic to connect to the DB and then start the Express server. The way you have it now, the Express server can begin handling requests before the DB is connected. Also, add labels to your logging so you know where each one comes from, eg `console.log("getUser", "connection state", mongoose.connection.readyState)`

Comment: This line `const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema,"users");` should not be inside `getUser` function since it only needs to be called once. Move it just above the `async function getUser(user...` and as pointed out by Phil you should invert the logic so first connect to db and then call `app.listen` which should also be placed down bellow the routes definition so you start listening after you define the routes.